# Searching using phpmysql

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to search a database using incomplete statements for example if a type jo, it returns results showing every thing that starts with jo using php mysql.
An example with codeigniter will be of much help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

May be you are looking for

```
SELECT *  FROM `table` WHERE `field` LIKE '%value%'
```

EDIT:-

```
$query = $this->db
         -> select("*")
         -> from("table")
         -> where("field '%value%'")
         -> get();
```

Comment: I am using codeigniter and its failing to work out. Can someone get me a codeigniter example. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

**Use AJAX**

Using ajax you can do the described task easily.

Use the **SELECT** query in ajax page.

```
`"SELECT *  FROM `table_name` WHERE `field_name` LIKE '$name%'"`
```

You can assign the typing values into '$name'
 '$name%' will returns the fields starts with the value you inserted..

THX